# add a python module with out root permission

Tags: python, module

I meet a problem when I try to install module omniORB&omniORBpy to a system, I don't have the root permission so I use --prefix to installed them to my user dir.

my question is : how can I make python load this module? I try add my user path to sys.path, but it still doesn't work.

Br,
J.K.

Comment: why aren't using virtualenv ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the search path by adding the directory to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` or by adding it to `sys.path` in your Python script. Both work; if they don't, then you're using the wrong path.

Comment: Hi, I try to add '/home/{user}/omniORB/','/home/{user}/omniORB/lib/python2.3/site-packages/' to sys.path, and then import omniORB, it works, but when I import CORBA, it raise a error,"ImportError: No module named _omnipy", I can import CORBA before I append sys.path, is there any conflict? should I compile a CORBA module to my user dir to fix? this?

Comment: sorry, I don't need compile a CORBA, it already in omniORB, in '/home/{user}/omniORB/lib/python2.3/site-packages/onmiORB/CORBA.py' 
and see the __init__.py of omniORB, it used _omniorb and didn't raise error when be imported, why CORBA.py raise this error?

Comment: You should avoid module conflicts (several modules with the same name) because that can lead to all kinds of strange problems. In your case, there seems to be more than one CORBA implementation and chances are that when you load the first version, it gets polluted with files from the second copy.

Comment: a module ORBit install by root conflict with omniORB, I still can't handle this problem, it seems I should use the system provide module, thanks anyway.

Comment: There is another option: You can copy all the system packages (except for ORBit) into your home directory and then set PYTHONHOME to the copy (see http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `--user` option instead of `--prefix`, since it installs it in `${HOME}/.local/lib/pythonx/site-packages` and thus it does not require to add the path to sys.path.

I think this option is available only for python 2.6 + but I am not sure.

If you have to install it in an other place, then you have no choice and I don't know what could be wrong.

By the way, maybe posting some sample code(just to see where exactly are the files and how you try to import them) would make clearer the "error".

Comment: I try to put it into ${HOME}/.local/lib/pythonx/site-packages, my python is 2.3, so seems it doesn't work,

Comment: @user not found I am sure that python 2.3 does not support per user site-ackages.